Logical consistency in proof for Real Cauchy sequence implies convergence
I have doubts about this proof I reproduced from a text I have been following.
Any help in full would be appreciated as it would really help me to get more familiar with the trickiness of analysis proofs!
Proof: Every real Cauchy sequence is convergent.
Let the sequence be $(a_n)$ and $(a_n)$ is bounded as it is Cauchy.
By Bolzano-Weierstrass $(a_n)$ has a convergent subsequence $(a_{n_k}) \to L$, say.
So let $\epsilon (>0)=\epsilon'/2$ where $\epsilon'\in \mathbb{R}\geq0$.
Then
$$ 
\exists N_1 \text{ such that } k \geq N_1 \implies |a_{n_k} - L| < \epsilon' / 2 $$
$$
\exists N_2 \text{ such that } m, n \geq N_2 \implies |a_m - a_n| < \epsilon' / 2
$$
Put $s := \min \{ k \mid n_k \geq N_2 \}$ and put $N = n_s$.
(Q.) So we are choosing k to be the smallest number such that if I go up to this index of the subsequence the corresponding main sequence index will be greater than $N_2$. This means that $s$ is defined such that $n_{s} \geq N_2 \geq s$. Then we say let $N=n_s$. Then we can say $|a_n-L| \leq |a_n-a_{n_s}| + |a_{n_s}-L| \leq \epsilon'/2 + \epsilon'/2$ if n>N as then the first term disappears as $n_s$ is already greater or equal to $N_2$ AND we need $n_s \geq N_1$ but so far we have not considered if $N_1 \geq N_2$. This is now a problem/loophole here right?
Then $$m, n \geq N \implies | a_m - a_n | \leq |a_m - a_{n_s}| + |a_{n_s} - l| < \epsilon' / 2 + \epsilon' / 2 = \epsilon' $$
(Q.) Should it not be $|a_m - l|$ to start with right? And then we want $m \geq N$ (assuming we fixed the loophole in (Q1.)) and we do not need to specify $n$ as this won't turn up in this main justification line?
Yes, I have seen this and posts alike before making this posting, but they do not capture my questions: Proving cauchy sequence is convergent sequence.

"This means that $s$ is defined such that $n_{s} \geq N_2 \geq s$": no, such that $n_s\ge N_2>n_{s-1}$.

To fix Q1, better define $s := \min { k\color{red}{\ge N_1} \mid n_k \geq N_2 }$. I agree with you for Q2, there should be no $n$.
